How do I return the correct builder from a builder hierarchy in a generic factory method?
I want to write a factory method that takes a generic builder as a parameter and returns the same type.
I created a class hierarchy with xjc with the jaxb-rich-contract-plugin and the -Xfluent-builder parameter. (But the issue is not with xjc, it's with how generics work.)
Then I wanted to create an API layer around the created classes with a factory class that encapsulate the setting of some common members.
Basically it looks like this: I have one (abstract) base class with some common fields and a bunch of derived classes with their own fields. The code that xjc generates includes inside each class a nice Builder class. That builder class is has a generic parameter to be able to forward the class that is to be created from the base class builder to the derived class Builders.
I tell you the most important stuff first. My handwritten factory class has a static method builder(...) that takes a builder from the class hierarchy as a parameter, sets the common fields and returns that builder again:
public class Factory {

  private final String commonField;

  public Factory(final String commonField) {
    this.commonField = commonField;
  }

  public <P, T extends Base> T.Builder<P> builder(final T.Builder<P> builder) {
    return builder.withCommonField(commonField);
  }

}

As you can see, the parameter is of type T.Builder<P> and the return type is the same.
The method withCommonField() is defined in the base builder and overridden in the derived builder, adhering to the Liskov Substitution Principle for the return type (narrowing it down):
    public Base.Builder<_B> withCommonField(final String commonField) {
      this.commonField = commonField;
      return this;
    }

and
    @Override
    public Derived.Builder<_B> withCommonField(final String commonField) {
      super.withCommonField(commonField);
      return this;
    }

So far so good. But when I now use that factory method I get a type error:
class FactoryTest {
  @Test
  void checkBuilderDerived() {
    final Factory factory = new Factory("bar");
    final Derived.Builder<Void> builder;
    builder = factory.builder(Derived.builder()); // <<< ERROR
    builder.withDerivedField("foo");
  }
}

The error is that factory.builder() returns a Base.Builder<> and not a Derived.Builder<>.
And the reason is that the compiler chooses for the call to withCommonField() the implementation of Base.Builder<>, which returns the Base.Builder<>:
    return builder.withCommonField(commonField);

If the compiler would choose the overridden method from the parameter Derived.Builder<> it would work. I.e. I can add an explicit type (not generic):
  public Derived.Builder<Void> derivedBuilder(final Derived.Builder<Void> builder) {
    return builder.withCommonField(commonField);
  }

and then call it:
   @Test
  void checkDerivedBuilder() {
    final Factory factory = new Factory("12");
    final var builder = factory.derivedBuilder(Derived.builder());
    builder.withDerivedField("34");
  }

That works, of course. But I would need to write a specific method for each of the generated classes. Meh.
I played around with casts to the generic type parameter type, but without success.
How do I tell the compiler that the call builder.withCommonField() is for the Dericed.Builder<>?

For completeness I have the simplified classes here. Remember that Base and Derived are auto-generated, but Factory is handwritten:
Base.java (simplified generated):

public class Base {

  protected String commonField;

  public Base() {
  }
  public Base(final Base _other) {
    this.commonField = _other.commonField;
  }

  public static <_B> Base.Builder<_B> builder() {
    return new Base.Builder<>(null, null, false);
  }

  // === Builder ===

  public static class Builder<_B> {
    protected final _B _parentBuilder;
    protected final Base _storedValue;
    private String commonField;

    public Builder(final _B _parentBuilder, final Base _other, final boolean _copy) {
      this._parentBuilder = _parentBuilder;
      if (_other != null) {
        if (_copy) {
          _storedValue = null;
          this.commonField = _other.commonField;
        } else {
          _storedValue = _other;
        }
      } else {
        _storedValue = null;
      }
    }

    protected <_P extends Base> _P init(final _P _product) {
      _product.commonField = this.commonField;
      return _product;
    }

    public Base.Builder<_B> withCommonField(final String commonField) {
      this.commonField = commonField;
      return this;
    }

    public Base build() {
      if (_storedValue == null) {
        return this.init(new Base());
      } else {
        return (Base) _storedValue;
      }
    }

  }

}

Derived.java (simplified generated):
public class Derived extends Base {

  protected String derivedField;

  public Derived() {
  }
  public Derived(final Derived _other) {
    super(_other);
    this.derivedField = _other.derivedField;
  }

  public static Derived.Builder<Void> builder() {
    return new Derived.Builder<>(null, null, false);
  }

  // === Builder ===

  public static class Builder<_B> extends Base.Builder<_B> {
    private String derivedField;

    public Builder(final _B _parentBuilder, final Derived _other, final boolean _copy) {
      super(_parentBuilder, _other, _copy);
      if(_other != null) {
        this.derivedField = ((_other.derivedField == null) ? null : _other.derivedField);
      }
    }

    protected <_P extends Derived> _P init(final _P _product) {
      _product.derivedField = this.derivedField;
      return super.init(_product);
    }

    public Derived.Builder<_B> withDerivedField(final String derivedField) {
      this.derivedField = derivedField;
      return this;
    }

    @Override
    public Derived.Builder<_B> withCommonField(final String commonField) {
      super.withCommonField(commonField);
      return this;
    }

    @Override
    public Derived build() {
      if (_storedValue == null) {
        return this.init(new Derived());
      } else {
        return (Derived) _storedValue;
      }
    }

  }

}

Factory.java (handwritten):
public class Factory {

  private final String commonField;

  public Factory(final String commonField) {
    this.commonField = commonField;
  }

  public <P, T extends Base> T.Builder<P> builder(final T.Builder<P> builder) {
    return builder.withCommonField(commonField);
  }

  public Derived.Builder<Void> derivedBuilder(final Derived.Builder<Void> builder) {
    return builder.withCommonField(commonField);
  }

}

FactoryTest.java (handwritten):
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

class FactoryTest {

  @Test
  void checkBuilderDerived() {
    final Factory factory = new Factory("12");
    final Derived.Builder<Void> builder;
    builder = factory.builder(Derived.builder());
    builder.withDerivedField("34");
  }

  @Test
  void checkDerivedBuilder() {
    final Factory factory = new Factory("12");
    final var builder = factory.derivedBuilder(Derived.builder());
    builder.withDerivedField("34");
  }

}


you could not catch the point of the factory pattern.
